# webpack 4 and webfonts-loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

webfonts-loader does not seam to work with webpack 4.
https://github.com/jeerbl/webfonts-loader

Tried everything to get webpack 4 working with webfonts-loader with the options or just using a myfont.font.js, tried with json and it is still the same, has anyone had any success getting this webfonts-loader generator to work with with webpack. I see no errors it just fails silently.

```
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
           // svg font generator and loader
           test: /\.font\.js/,
           use: [
               'css-loader',
            {
        loader: 'webfonts-loader',
        options: {
        'files': [
        './whatever-font.svg'
    ],
    'fontName': 'customName',
    'dest': 'customfontfolder',
    'types': ['eot', 'woff', 'woff2', 'ttf', 'svg'],
    'fileName': '[fontname].[hash].[ext]' 
}}]},]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you will need to use file-loader in this case. And you have test font extension like this

```
{
   test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
   loader: "file-loader"
}
```

You can read my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)